# Python: words replacing in huge text

Tags: python, text, replace

I have a huge text and a list of words ~10K. 
What is the fastest way in Python to replace all this words in text with some other word?

EDIT: 
Text size >1Gb, text is human written, and "extremely tokenized" (any runs of alphanumeric characters and any other single symbols was splitted into new tokens)

a number of words >10K, each word frequency in text is 1
the replacement word is same in all replacements.
Python 2.5-2.7

Comment: Do you mean you have 10000 words in the list or your text has a size of 10000 bytes? What is bigger, the word list or the text?

Comment: Text size >1Gb, and a number of words >10K.

Comment: What version of python?  Does each search term correspond to a replacement term, or are you replacing all search terms with the same replacement term?  How 'regular' is the text to start out with?  Space delimited, punctuation, variable?

Comment: text is human written, and "extremely tokenized" (any runs of alphanumeric characters and any other single symbols was splitted into new tokens); each word frequency in text is 1 the replacement word is same in all replacements. Python 2.5-2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input format and search / replace pairings info is going to necessary to refine this answer if it comes close to start with, but this would be my initial stab at it (assuming some form of regularity in the input data, space delimited in my example code below).

```
replacements = {
  's1': 'r1',
  's2': 'r2'
  ...
}

with open('input.txt') as fhi, open('output.txt', 'w') as fho:
  for line in fhi:
    words = line.split(' ')

    fho.write(' '.join(map(lambda w: replacements.get(w, w), words))

    # Or as a list comprehension from the comments.
    fho.write(' '.join([replacements.get(w, w) for w in words]))
```

The idea here is that we'll be relocating data into an output file from an input file.  For each word of each line, we check to see if it's in our replacements dictionary.  We retrieve the new value if it is, or return the word unchanged otherwise via the `dict.get(key[, default])` method.  This may not be ideal, doesn't handle punctuation, would probably have trouble on an input file that wasn't broken into lines, etc, but may be a way to get started.

Comment: Note, I've leveraged the 2.7 syntax for `with` that supports multiple files.  If you're working with 2.5 or 2.6 you'll have to nest with statements in order to deal with two files (or create a custom context manager that handles more than one file).

Comment: Thanks, your solution ' '.join(map(lambda w: replacements.get(w, w), words)) is very fast in my case (load all data in the memory + "extremely tokenized" text).

Comment: @Alex - Glad to help.  Be sure to tag an answer if you've found an approach that works so that people don't continue to try to solve it for you.  :)

Comment: how does this compare in performance to a list comprehension? out.write( ' '.join( [ replacements.get( w, w ) for w in line.split() ] )

Comment: @dusktreader - The list comprehension may actually end up being a bit faster, is definitely possible.  I'll update the answer to include it as an alternate.  Thanks!

Comment: @g.d.d.c  It would be interesting to benchmark this.  I would be curious to see how lambda expressions compare with list comprehensions

Comment: With the list comprehension speed up from 0.58-0.61 to 0.47-0.48 s

Answer (score 1):

Wow! This is not trivial at all. Here is an idea:

```
Step 1: Quantize the text into words, signs etc. 
        The function quantize accepts text as an argument, 
        the output is the list of words and signs. 
        def quantize(text: str) -> list: 
            ...
        An inverse function that can construct the a from a given list:
        def dequantize(lst: list) -> str:
            ....

Step 2: Build a dictionary of quantized list, so that 
        d_rep[word] = word
        Then, use the replacements word lists to transform this dictionary as follows:
        d_rep[word] = replacement

Step 3: Go through every word in quantized list and replace it with a value from 
        d_rep dictionary. It might be the original word or a replacement. 

Step 4: Dequantize the list and restore the text.
```

This should be optimal enough if you have a big text and a huge amount of search/replace words. Good luck! Ask, if you have any implementation questions.

**Update:**
With a single replacement word, it's even easier, create a set from the '10K' wordlist, and then for every word in quantized list, if word in set, replace it in that list.

In a pseudo-python-code:

```
qlist = quantize(text)

for i in range(0, len(qlist)):
    word = qlist[i]
    if word in wordlist_set:
        qlist[i] = 'replacement'

text = dequantize(qlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method, if you have enough memory, may be to read the text as a string and use regex to search for and perform the replacements:

```
def replace(matched):
    # Matched.group(0) is the word that was found
    # Return the replacement
    return "REPLACEMENT"

# The \b ensure that only whole words are matched.
text = re.sub(r"\b(%s)\b" % "|".join(words), replace, text)
```

If you don't have the memory, try doing it in chunks, perhaps:

```
# Read a chunk and a line to ensure that you're not truncating a word.
chunk = text_file.read(1024 ** 2) + text_file.readline()
```

Comment: I got an error: OverflowError: regular expression code size limit exceeded

Comment: There's an regex implementation on PyPI which should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a simple approach, replacing one line a time:

```
pattern1 = 'foo'
pattern2 = 'bar'

with open('input.txt') as input, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
        output.write(line.replace(pattern1, pattern2))
```